# What is the direction of wavevector in the real hexagonal phononic lattice?

Tags: photons, solid-state-physics, phonons

Assuming we have a 2D hexagonal lattice and its reciprocal lattice. The difference between them is that the real lattice and its reciprocal lattice have 30° rotation. So if the following image is its first Brillouin zone, we have a direction $Γk$ in reciprocal lattice, is this direction kept the same in the real lattice or it also need to be rotated 30°？
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the direction of the wave vector or the direction the wave travels? (I.e. the direction energy moves.) In general, the two are not the same thing.

The direction of the wavevector (i.e. $\vec{k}$ in $e^{i\left(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t\right)}$) is exactly what it looks like in reciprocal space.

For the direction of propagation, in general, you'll need to find the dispersion relation and find its [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#In_three_dimensions) $\vec{v}_g\left(\vec{k}\right) = \nabla_\vec{k} \omega \left(\vec{k}\right)$. The direction of the group velocity at the wavevector of interest is the direction of propagation.

That said, I'm pretty sure that, because of symmetry, the direction of propagation and the direction of the wavevector are the same at a high-symmetry point like k. That said, you can find the dispersion relation and check.

Comment: What I am asking is that the direction of wave vector in real lattice and the direction of wave vector in reciprocal space. and thank you very much for answering my question.